# ASP.NET Core Rest API Saving Failed saying no access to another database

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

My ASP.NET Core Rest API is returning a 500 Internal Server Error on post method while adding a new customer. I am able to get data from my development database, but `myDbContext.SaveChanges();` failed saying my development user doesn't have access to the main database, but my connection string refers to my development database only.

- My database name : `MyappDbDev`
- My database user : `AppUserDev`

Error:

> The server principal "AppUserDev" is not able to access the database "MyappDbDev" under the current security context

I have another database in production with following credentials:

- Database name : `MyappDb`
- Database user : `AppUser`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any useful suggestions after researching for days, at last I found that I had a trigger for the table that I am adding new record.
which the trigger had insert command to old database.

It was a silly mistake , but I hope this may help someone someday.